# Switch language (audio and lyric) seamlessly in Adobe Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, adobe

I’m creating a multilingual flash game with multilingual narrations. Till now i’ve got one language with an audio stream and lyric to accompany it in it’s own timeline controlled by a button on the main timeline to pause and play. I would like to add 2 more languages with audio and own lyric(karaoke style) for each language in this scene. And eventually have buttons on the main timeline that would switch the language(audio and lyric) and seamlessly continue from where the last language left off. Till now I have this action from the main timeline controlling the audio and lyric. englyr being the movie clip, with audio and lyric in it.

```
toggleButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleClick3);
toggleButton.buttonState = "off";

function toggleClick3(event:MouseEvent) {
    if (toggleButton.buttonState == "on") {
        englyr.play();
        toggleButton.buttonState = "off";
    } else {
        toggleButton.buttonState = "on";
        englyr.stop();
    }
}
```

I’m assuming I should put the other 2 languages as well as their lyric in englyr so that I can disable/mute languages that are not needed to be heard or seen. One problem is I can’t group the lyric and the narration(2 layers) together as a movie clip in that timeline. Therefore cannot disable the 2 other languages that shouldn’t be heard or seen. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to let them both play from code instead of via the timeline.
The first thing to do is to go to the settings of your audioclips in the library, enable "Export for Actionscript" and set a different class name for both your clips. I have named mine "english" and "french".
The following code manages two sounds and changes the language when you press the button of a language that is currently not playing.

```
var englishClip:Sound = new english(); //load both sounds.
var frenchClip:Sound = new french();

//create the sound and the sound channel.
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var mySound:Sound = englishClip;

//if you want to have lots of different languages it might be easier to just have different buttons instead of one with a state.
englishButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SpeakEnglish);
frenchButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SpeakFrench);

//we'll start with having just the english sound playing.
myChannel = mySound.play();

function SpeakEnglish(event:MouseEvent) {
    if (mySound != englishClip) { //if the english sound is already playing, do nothing.
        var currentPlayPosition:Number = myChannel.position; //save playback position.
        myChannel.stop(); //stop playing
        mySound = englishClip.play(currentPlayPosition); //resume playing from saved position.
}

function SpeakFrench(event:MouseEvent) {
    if (mySound != frenchClip) { //if the French sound is already playing, do nothing.
        var currentPlayPosition:Number = myChannel.position; //save playback position.
        myChannel.stop(); //stop playing
        mySound = frenchClip.play(currentPlayPosition); //resume playing from saved position.
}
```

This could all be made more compact by having a single function that you pass the appropriate sound to. It would look something like this:

```
function SpeakEnglish(event:MouseEvent) {
    ChangeSound(englishClip);
}

function SpeakFrench(event:MouseEvent) {
    ChangeSound(frenchClip);
}

function ChangeSound(newSound:Sound){
    if (mySound != newSound) { //if the sound is already playing, do nothing.
        var currentPlayPosition:Number = myChannel.position; //save playback position.
        myChannel.stop(); //stop playing
        mySound = newSound.play(currentPlayPosition); //resume playing from saved 
}
```

And that should solve the problem, i hope that helped :)

Resource: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/

Comment: hmmm I was using the audio with code like you said but the karaoke lyric along with it was getting out of sync with the audio. I'll give it a go later on today and will let you know

Comment: Symbol 'enlyrvult', Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 11, Line 24 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.media:SoundChannel to an unrelated type flash.media:Sound.
Symbol 'enlyrvult', Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 11, Line 31 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.media:SoundChannel to an unrelated type flash.media:Sound.

Comment: i've managed to get it to work but other problems are springing up. thanks a lot for your time and quick answer